# Как задать цвет текста в EditText?

Tags: android, xml

Как правильно задать цвет текста в `EditText`, чтобы при темной теме он был белый, а при белой черный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант использовать такую проверку:

```
switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        …
        break;
    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
        …
        break; 
}
```

так же вот например на котлине:

```
val currentNightMode = configuration.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK
when (currentNightMode) {
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {} // Night mode is not active, we're using the light theme
    Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {} // Night mode is active, we're using dark theme
}
```

либо сделать отдельный метод:

```
fun Context.isDarkThemeOn(): Boolean {
    return resources.configuration.uiMode and 
            Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK == UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES
}
```

и дальше просто меняйте в зависимости от значений стиль вашего поля для ввода. [Вот документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme) по определению текущей темы системы. Цвет текста можно задать например так:

```
EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.revieew);
text.setTextColor(color);
```